# How to set branch permissions using az-cli?

Tags: git, azure-devops, azure-cli

I'm trying to deny the Edit Policies permission from a subject for the *develop* branch. I was under the impression this command would work:

```
$ az devops security permission update --allow-bit 2048 --subject foo@bar.com --namespace-id ***** --token repoV2/<project id>/<git repo id>/refs^heads^develop/
```

Despite the response

```
[
  {
    "acesDictionary": {
      "Microsoft.IdentityModel.Claims.ClaimsIdentity;****\\foo@bar.com": {
        "allow": 2048,
        "deny": 0,
        "descriptor": "Microsoft.IdentityModel.Claims.ClaimsIdentity;****\\foo@bar.com",
        "extendedInfo": {
          "effectiveAllow": 20342
        },
        "resolvedPermissions": [
          {
            "bit": 2048,
            "displayName": "Edit policies",
            "effectivePermission": "Allow",
            "name": "EditPolicies"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    "includeExtendedInfo": true,
    "inheritPermissions": true,
    "token": "repoV2/***/***/refs^heads^develop"
  }
]
```

The permission remains the same.

I think the token- and namespace id's are correct because the command works when using the token `repoV2/***/***/`.

Comment: So, if I'm not mistaken, the token for a branch named 'develop' should end with '/refs/heads/646576656c6f70/' ?

Comment: develop: `refs/heads/64006500760065006c006f007000/`. You need to use 00 to connect each alphabet.

Comment: That was it ! I hope they'll document this in the reference manual.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the format of the `az devops security permission update`:

```
az devops security permission update --id
                                     --subject
                                     --token
                                     [--allow-bit]
                                     [--deny-bit]
                                     [--org]
```

From you azure cli command, the cause of the problem should be the parameters.

You could get these parameters in Browser F12 Network Tool.

Here are the steps:

Step1: Navigate to the branch permission and press F12 to open the NetWork tool.
Then you could select the network tab.

Step2: Try to change the permssion.

Step3: You could check the network record and get these parameters.

[image]

Here is an example about the azure cli:

```
az devops security permission update --id 2e9eb7ed-3c0a-47d4-87c1-0ffdd275fd87 --subject xxx@xxx.com --token repoV2/92c1c5e8-d842-4698-b3f5-45d69e25624c/34439f96-646e-4aa0-a3e5-a55742a9813e/refs/heads/310032003400/ --allow-bit 0 --deny-bit 2048 --org https://dev.azure.com/orgname
```

**Note:** the `branch parameter` in token needs to be the  hex `id` (e.g. refs/heads/310032003400/).

Based on my test, if you use the branch name, it **doesn't** change the permission.

Here is a ticket about [convert branch name to hex id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58529566/getting-the-branch-id-for-accesscontrol).