# Bypass build validation policy on branch and autocomplete for some users in. azure devops

Tags: azure-devops, devops, developer-tools

I want to bypass branch policy such that when a particular allowed user creates a PR in azure devops then it bypass the branch policy and autocompletes.

I need bash task so.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Azure policies (and programming them with scripts) have nothing to do with Git except to the extent that they run some Git command; when they do run some Git command and it behaves in a way that you don't understand, that would be a Git question. (Note that Git itself does not have pull requests: those are an Azure add-on.)

Comment: Is there any update for this issue? Feel free to let me know if the answer could give you some help. Just a reminder of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: Yes, we are using this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/repos/pr?view=azure-cli-latest) and found the options to bypass the PR.

By bypassing PR, we autocomplete the PR also.

Comment: Also we have already updated the branch security to allow certain selected person to bypass the policy.

Answer (score 2):

> I want to bypass branch policy such that when a particular allowed user creates a PR in azure devops then it bypass the branch policy and autocompletes.

You could set the [Bypass branch policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/branch-policies?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#bypass-branch-policies):

> Bypass permissions let you push changes to a branch directly, or
> complete pull requests that don't satisfy branch policies. You can
> grant bypass permissions to a user or group. You can scope bypass
> permissions to an entire project, a repo, or a single branch.

You could go to the **Project settings** under **Repos** select **Repositories** and then fine the **Branches** node under the project you want to set the policy for：

[image]

[image]

**Note:** It will bypass all the branch policies, not only the Bypass build validation policy on branch.

You could check the document [Azure DevOps Repos: Bypass Branch Policies](https://elanderson.net/2020/05/azure-devops-repos-bypass-branch-policies/) for some more details.

Comment: Can you please try with this [link] (https://docs.azure.cn/zh-cn/cli/repos/pr?view=azure-cli-latest#commands)
I need this to be done with bash script and to be used in yaml file
@Leo Liu-MSFT

Comment: @MIHIRUPADHYAY, Sure. But update the security of the branch, we should use another link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/devops/security/permission?view=azure-cli-latest#az-devops-security-permission-update. Your link is used to update the branch policy not the security . There is [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62915534/how-to-set-branch-permissions-using-az-cli) about this issue, you could check the answer for some more details.